# Is there a linear transformation such that $M^2 (1- M) =0$ but $M$ is not idempotent?

Tags: linear-algebra

> find  a linear transformation such that $M^2 (1- M)  =0$ but $M$ is not idempotent ?

My attempt :  i take take the vector space generated by the base $\{e_1, e_2\}$ and define $T(e_1)=e_2$,and $T(e_2)=e_1 $

Comment: Well, did your attempt work or not?

Comment: @TomGrubb actually im not able to find  such linear transformation

Comment: We want $M^2=M^3$ but $M\neq M^2$. This shows that $M$ can‘t be invertible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know $M$ is idempotent if and only if $M^2=M$, and the assumption is that $M^3=M^2$. So is it possible that $M^2\neq M$ but $M^3=M^2$? Clearly not if $M$ is invertible, because $M^3=M^2$ would imply $M^2=M$.

Now we know that $x^2$ divides the minimal polynomial of $M$, and thus we necessarily have a nontrivial Jordan block with eigenvalue $0$. For example, consider

$$M=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can assume with no loss of generality that $M$ is in Jordan Normal form.